# Squid systemd service not run at boot

Tags: debian, systemd, squid

I compiled squid 3 from source and installed in `/usr/local/squid/` on my debian jessie computer. I want to start squid at boot. The following code is my `squid.service` which located in `/etc/systemd/system/squid.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Squid Proxy

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/squid/sbin/squid -f /usr/local/squid/etc/squid.conf -d1
ExecStop=/usr/local/squid/sbin/squid -k shutdown

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Install at boot:

```
systemctl start squid
systemctl enable squid
```

But after restart. Squid is not run at boot.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but why not install the [`squid3`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/squid3) available in Debian 8 (Jessie)?

Comment: @StephenKitt I am trying to write my own systemd service to understand how a service works.

Comment: Are you using Networkmanager to manage the Network?

Comment: @GAD3R I installed a debian minimal. I did not install any Networkmanager packages.

Comment: @K.Lotus . What does `journalctl -xn` say to you right after you boot? Does it gives any clue why squid is not being started?

Comment: try adding in the `[Unit]` section `After=network.target` to delay the start until the network is partly up.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to create a daemon script then link a starter link on the required run level to start your squid.

For example:

```
cp /etc/init.d/skeleton /etc/init.d/squid
```

then implement start() & stop() and restart() if needed. Now you need to link the created daemon to the desired run level but make sure that it has a sequence number after networking or network-manager for example:
if your desired run level is 5
cd /etc/rc5.d/
ls -l

you will find some thing like

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Jun 16  2015 S08iptables -> ../init.d/iptables
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Jun 16  2015 S10network -> ../init.d/network
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Jun 16  2015 S11netplugd -> ../init.d/netplugd`

So you need to run the following

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/squid /etc/rc5.d/S88squid
```

...... Restart your server and test

Please note that jessie debian has the two orientation of service management systemclt and the old daemon style.

Comment: The OP is looking for a systemd unit, not an initscript. Also, to link an initscript into the `/etc/rc?.d` tree you should use `update-rc.d` instead of linking files manually.

Comment: OP is looking to learn `systemd` units.